# PHP image: Image wont show in PHP Profile page

Tags: php, css, image, function, image-processing

I have just made a profile page in PHP  for a user which displays user profile information including their picture, The image is stored on the database and everytime when I upload an image on the web page, the database does work and update the database profile section but it is not showing on the web browser. :/ i tried different browsers but every browser failed to display the image, the Alt parameter of image does show but no image, i have inspected the page element the image path is there but i can't see the image there?

the code in the profile page is:

```
<?php
function change_profile_image($userID, $file_temp, $file_extn) {
$file_path ='C:/xampp/htdocs/cricket/user/images/profile/'. substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `profile` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "' WHERE `userID` = " . (int)$userID);
}
?>
<?php
 $query = "select * from user where userID='".$_SESSION['id']."'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
 ?>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
 <div id="content">
 <h1>Edit Your Information</h1>

    <div class="profile">
        <?php
        if (isset($_FILES['profile'])=== true) {
            if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
                echo "Please choose a file!";
          } else {
            $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

            $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
            $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
            $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

            if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed)=== true) {
                change_profile_image($_SESSION['id'], $file_temp, $file_extn);
            } else {
                echo "incorrect file type, Allowed: ";
                echo implode(', ', $allowed);
            }
            }
        }   
        if (empty($row['profile']) === false) {
            echo '<img src="', $row['profile'], '" alt="', $row['user_firstname'], '\'s Profile Image">';
        }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="profile"> <br> <input type="submit">
        </form>
     </div> 
    <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="txtbox1">Email</div>
   <div class="txtbox">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['user_email']?>">  </div><br><br><br>
   <div class="txtbox1">First Name</div>
   <div class="txtbox">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $row['user_firstname']?>"></div><br><br><br>
   <div class="txtbox1">Surname</div>
   <div class="txtbox">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $row['user_surname']?>"></div><br><br><br>
   <div class="txtbox1">DOB</div>
   <div class="txtbox">
   <input type="text" name="dob" value="<?php echo $row['user_dob']?>"></div><br>
   <div class="txtbox"><input type="submit" value="update" name="update">  </div>
   </form>

   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['update'])){

   $query1 = "update user set user_email='".$_POST['email']."',  user_firstname='".$_POST['firstname']."', user_surname='".$_POST['lastname']."',  user_dob='".$_POST['dob']."' where userID='".$_SESSION['id']."'"; 
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
    echo "<script>alert('Your Information has been changed SuccessFully..'); window.location = './edit.php';</script>";

  }
  ?>        
 </div>
```

If anyone is interested in the CSS the styling code is:

```
.profile {
background:white;
border:1px dashed #ccc;
padding:5px;
}

.profile img {
width=100%;
}
```

i will really appreciate if anyone can guide me or help me in the right direction

Comment: thanks for your input chris but i followed a tutorial and thats how it was done there so i just learned the person did exactly that way :/ in the tutorial the person did exactly like that and it worked

Comment: Actually yea, that will work for echo, not for setting values in the future, but that'd be a separate issue not to worry about. If you view the network tab of your developer tools does it show a request for the image? Can you post the HTML you are getting for the image?

Comment: Your browser wants a path from your website's root, not from c:

Comment: hi chris i am getting this from the page inspect of browser
<img src="C:/xampp/htdocs/cricket/user/images/profile/0ed0f37104.png" alt="zain's Profile Image">

Comment: Hi BigScar how do i do that? i just followed tutorial and in the tutorial it worked :/

Comment: I think it ought to start <img src="/cricket/user/images/profile/'. and so on and so forth.

Comment: thanks BigScar the image area got bigger but the image is still not showing its coming out like a broken image or sumin

Comment: The path should start from the same directory that your script is executing in unless you've defined something else. Try putting the image file in the same folder with your script and do <img src="0ed0f37104.png>"